# No (La)TeX syntax highlighting on mobile devices

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, ios-app, android-app

Here is a view of [a code block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235318/5764) on the full site (viewed through mobile/iPhone):

[image]

Here is a view of the same code block on the mobile site:

[image]

Here is a view of the same code block using the Stack Exchange App (from [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8)... I'm sure it's similar on other devices):

[image]

None of the mobile versions show the proper, default, (La)TeX (`lang-latex`, `lang-tex`) syntax highlighting. Can this be enabled for the mobile versions on this site?

Reference: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/168244)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**  This has been fixed in the apps for a while now.  There's no highlighting on mobile web because that's not a feature anywhere on the network.  [Here's the feature request on MSE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132636/why-is-the-code-syntax-color-highlight-gone-in-the-mobile-view)

---

Look at the beautiful red color of 12pt in the iPhone app.  We're doing something!

The problem with the problem with the mobile apps is that the web has a concept of site level languages for syntax highlighting but hasn't exposed that to the apps. There are so many nuanced rules for sites it's overwhelming. Since there are only four sites that do this right now, I'm hardcoding it into the app and it will be in an upcoming release (not the next one but the one after).

[image: A screenshot of the app with same post from the question with proper highlighting.]

<strike>As far as mobile web goes, it looks like syntax highlighting is occurring, just none of the styling is coming through. I've pinged the design team about that.</strike>

Comment: How often are the apps updated? Does it differ between Apple and other providers?

Comment: @Werner The iOS app has been getting updates about every 2 months.  Android is probably similar.  An update is going to the app store right now (without this fix) so I anticipate the next release probably mid May.

Comment: Any progress on pinging the people who might know what's going on or fix this?